# Adding headers to HttpClient results in "Misused header name" error

Tags: c#, header, httpclient

The error I get is `"System.InvalidOperationException: 'Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.'"`

```
private async void Scanner_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                string strProduct = "banana";

           // Create the HttpContent for the form to be posted.
            var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("", ""),
            });

            requestContent.Headers.Add("authority", "secure.bananastore12.com.au");
            requestContent.Headers.Add("pragma", "no-cache");
            requestContent.Headers.Add("cache-control", "no-cache");
            requestContent.Headers.Add("accept", "*/*");
            requestContent.Headers.Add("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");
            requestContent.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36");
            requestContent.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            requestContent.Headers.Add("sec-fetch-site", "same-origin");
            requestContent.Headers.Add("sec-fetch-dest", "empty");
            requestContent.Headers.Add("referer", "https://secure.bananastore12.com.au/plu?product=coconut");
            requestContent.Headers.Add("accept-language", "en-AU,en;q=0.9,ja-JP;q=0.8,ja;q=0.7,en-GB;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.5");
            requestContent.Headers.Add("cookie", "SWI=Q8pvqi0My8Tr06_qcIth0zZ8RJ_3A70eZvjCHgyHDorAQkcZd");

            // Get the response.
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
                $"https://secure.bananastore12.com.au/api/products/plu?product={strProduct}",
                requestContent);
```

I have this CURL command that I am trying to convert, but other stack overflow posts don't show how to add headers so im giving it my best go.

```
 curl 'https://secure.bananastore12.com.au/api/products/plu?product=banana' \
      -H 'authority: secure.bananastore12.com.au' \
      -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
      -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
      -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="88", "Google Chrome";v="88", ";Not A Brand";v="99"' \
      -H 'accept: */*' \
      -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' \
      -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
      -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36' \
      -H 'content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
      -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
      -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
      -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
      -H 'referer: https://secure.bananastore12.com.au/plu?product=coconut' \
      -H 'accept-language: en-AU,en;q=0.9,ja-JP;q=0.8,ja;q=0.7,en-GB;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.5' \
      -H 'cookie: _ga=GA1.3.155688641.160309227; __zlcmid=10kjWKhNAJv5m; _fbp=fb.2.160309258218.178001962; _ga=GA1.4.155886413.163092227; _rdt_uuid=16030257507.af1d30fe-fd4-4220-afe-8b7cddf020e; _hjid=55067e1-75d7-439d-127-9e2c667ad; _delighted_web={%22OcuKtEiqfXoNzxC22:{%22_delighted_fst%22:{%22t%22:%221603095074335%22}%2C%22_delighted_lst%22:{%22t%22:%22160304%22%2C%22m%22:{%22token%22:%22Hjrw1uPZRNIMQ652ZTbsTe%22}}%2C%22_delighted_lrt%22:{%22t%21603095081812%22%2C%22m%22:{%22token%22:%22HjrGrNIMQ652ZTbsTe%22}}}}; _gcl_au=1.1.1986940.1613605; _gid=GA1.3.10917049.16552602; aft=CfDJ8DLOaWzzk3AT6PvINsyqE; _hjTLDTest=1; _gat_UA-32960230-1=1; _hjIncludedInPageviewSample=1; LoginFlow=true; SWI=R08M_YnPionIWwUG0PcXlKOGjinqcA4; timeout=1655340169930' \
      --compressed
```

How is one suppose to add headers?

Answer (score 0):

When I have to create similar requests, I use *Postman*.
So, You need to import your curl  and than click 'Code snippets',  choose c# and you will have a request.
Postmans use RestClient, but you can simply rewrite it to your HttpClient, the most important thing there are headers and cookies that you need.

Here your code

```
var client = new RestClient("https://secure.bananastore12.com.au/api/products/plu?

product=banana");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("authority", "secure.bananastore12.com.au");
request.AddHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua", "\"Chromium\";v=\"88\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"88\", \";Not A Brand\";v=\"99\"");
request.AddHeader("accept", "*/*");
request.AddHeader("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");
request.AddHeader("sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0");
client.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36";
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
request.AddHeader("sec-fetch-site", "same-origin");
request.AddHeader("sec-fetch-mode", "cors");
request.AddHeader("sec-fetch-dest", "empty");
request.AddHeader("referer", "https://secure.bananastore12.com.au/plu?product=coconut");
request.AddHeader("accept-language", "en-AU,en;q=0.9,ja-JP;q=0.8,ja;q=0.7,en-GB;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.5");
request.AddHeader("cookie", "_ga=GA1.3.155688641.160309227; __zlcmid=10kjWKhNAJv5m; _fbp=fb.2.160309258218.178001962; _ga=GA1.4.155886413.163092227; _rdt_uuid=16030257507.af1d30fe-fd4-4220-afe-8b7cddf020e; _hjid=55067e1-75d7-439d-127-9e2c667ad; _delighted_web={%22OcuKtEiqfXoNzxC22:{%22_delighted_fst%22:{%22t%22:%221603095074335%22}%2C%22_delighted_lst%22:{%22t%22:%22160304%22%2C%22m%22:{%22token%22:%22Hjrw1uPZRNIMQ652ZTbsTe%22}}%2C%22_delighted_lrt%22:{%22t%21603095081812%22%2C%22m%22:{%22token%22:%22HjrGrNIMQ652ZTbsTe%22}}}}; _gcl_au=1.1.1986940.1613605; _gid=GA1.3.10917049.16552602; aft=CfDJ8DLOaWzzk3AT6PvINsyqE; _hjTLDTest=1; _gat_UA-32960230-1=1; _hjIncludedInPageviewSample=1; LoginFlow=true; SWI=R08M_YnPionIWwUG0PcXlKOGjinqcA4; timeout=1655340169930");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but this also results in the error I most see ```Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.```.

I theorize this is because the cookie isn't being set properly, as when doing a request on an url that doesn't need a cookie works.

Even with your code it gives the same error. At this point I have no hope left. I will have to try to hack my (barely working) python code into the rest of my C# app.

I guess python has some specific latest standard of some library that the site uses and c# doesn't.

Comment: Maybe cookies are expired? Try to set new ones. Good luck!

Comment: I generate and use the latest cookies each time, thanks :)